# Dynamic currency format on input field

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I would like to ask you is it possible to format dynamically input value?
So when I'm entering some value it will dynamically add commas to format currency.
For example I'm writing 1234 and it will be formatted to 1'234 dynamically.
If I delete one number it will be changed to 123.
I'm thinking about some custom binding. But is it possible to add a rule for every change?

Cheer

Comment: just google around computed observable

Comment: I forgot to mention that I know that's possible to do it with computed observable. But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it custom binding?

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sD6y4/ you can modify yourself if you are good at javascript. see the valueAsCurrency custom binding in it

Comment: i have made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sD6y4/27/  just enter number and then you see its formatted as you wished. Althoough it has many issues but can give you good idea. Hope it helps you

Comment: No it's not. Because it's adding only once the comma. I want to add this formatting on input not in <p>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already write what I need :)

Here is my working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/687zv5u0/2/)

And my code:

```
function TestViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myCurrency = ko.observable();
}

ko.bindingHandlers.currencyFormat = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'keyup', function (event) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(formatInput(element.value));
        observable.notifySubscribers(5);
    });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(value);
  }
};

function formatInput(value) {
  value += '';

  value = value.replace(/,/g, '');
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(value)) {
    value = value.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }

  return value;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
});
```

Enjoy it

Answer (score 6):

You can use [bindinghandler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for this and create a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numeric = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       var positions= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions) || ko.bindingHandlers.numeric.defaultPositions;
       var formattedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(positions); 
       var finalFormatted = ko.bindingHandlers.numeric.withCommas(formattedValue);  

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return finalFormatted; });
    },
    defaultPositions: 2,
    withCommas: function(original){
       original+= '';
        x = original.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;      
    } 
};
```

Then if you bind your value to the element, you just use this binding instead of the normal `text` binding:

```
<span data-bind="numeric: myNumericObservable"></span>
```

The custom binding handler above formats the value to the German value: `1.202,22` But you can easily change it by replacing the '.' and the ','.

By the way, here is a solution for numeric value bindings in `input`-tags:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function (event) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var positions= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue.defaultPositions;      

            if(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions)==0){
                positions=0;
            }

            if(isNaN(parseFloat($(element).val())))
                observable(0);
            else {
                if(!ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().noDecimalPoints))
                    observable(parseFloat($(element).val().replace(".","").replace(",",".")).toFixed(positions).replace(",","."));
                else 
                    observable(parseFloat($(element).val().replace(".","").replace(",",".")).toFixed(positions));
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(value!=null) {
            var positions= ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions) || ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue.defaultPositions;      
            if(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().positions)==0){
                positions=0;
            }
            var formattedValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(positions); 
            var finalFormatted  = formattedValue;
            if(!ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().noDecimalPoints))
                finalFormatted = ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue.withCommas(formattedValue); 
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, function() { return finalFormatted; });
        }
    },
    defaultPositions: 2,
    noDecimalPoints:false,
    withCommas: function(original){
       original+= '';
        x = original.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;      
    } 
};
```

You can use this as follows:

```
<input tabindex="10" data-bind="numericValue: myNumericObservable">
```

You can also configuarte it:

```
<input data-bind="numericValue: myNumericObservable, positions: 0, noDecimalPoints: true">
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. I prepare a [JSFiddler](http://www.jsfiddle.net/e3pkqLww/1/) which show what I want to do. I use a ko.pureComputed but I need a bindinghandler. Deleting is not working. Any idea How can I write a binding with same functionality(it's updating my input value) I don't want to use computed because I will have many of input like this.

Comment: I already prepare working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/687zv5u0/) but with ko.pureComputed() . Any idea how can change it to bindingHandlers?